# Migrating established web application to using requirejs - how to ensure modules are loaded when we need to use them?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Our pages are constructed with jsp. We have large page specific javascript files that we are in the process of refactoring into modules. So far, we have a script tag in the HEAD to load requirejs. The data-main js file is just loading the require.config settings and includes callback function a require(['common/userAgent']); to get this userAgent module loaded.

The page onload() calls a function in the big page specific js file that immediately needs the userAgent module, but when that function tries the require('common/userAgent') we get the error saying it hasn't been loaded yet and to use [] to load it.

Also, our page has many SCRIPTS tags intermingled with HTML and we'll need to use these modules from that code.

I'm trying to follow the [multi-page example](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage) except in that one it is loading the page.js from the data-main js file. I see why that is important to ensure dependencies are loaded as defined.

Is there a way to ensure dependencies are loaded when not in a requirejs module where you have defined the dependencies in the define(). I mean can we get these requirejs modules from straight javascript using the require() function without worry about whether the module has been async loaded yet, or not?